# How to take out ONLY the eureka ill service application instance to avoid hystrix circuit breaking?

Tags: spring-cloud, microservices, hystrix, netflix-eureka, netflix-feign

I'm trying out on my local machine the [spring-cloud-samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples) and I have developed a simple REST service with eureka and hystrix support.

I have a frontend application which connects to the service via a hystrix command method (@HystrixCommand annotated method) containing a reference to a Feign client.

Feign Client

```
@FeignClient("product-service")
public interface ProductClient {

    @RequestMapping(value = "product-service/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    Product getProduct(@PathVariable("id") int id);

}
```

Hystrix Wrapper

```
@Service
public class ProductHystrixClient {

    private final ProductClient productClient;

    @Autowired
    public ProductHystrixClient(ProductClient productClient) {
        this.productClient = productClient;
    }

    @HystrixCommand(groupKey = "product-service", commandKey = "getProduct", fallbackMethod = "getProductFallback")
    public Product getProduct(int id) {
        return productClient.getProduct(id);
    }

    public Product getProductFallback(int id) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

I've started two instances of the Spring MVC ProductService. The first one delivers, as expected, product information based on the given identifier. On the other hand, the second one throws always a RuntimeException in order to simulate a system dependency failure :

```
  if (1==1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("system dependency failure");
```

On the frontend side I use the hystrix client to get product information and the ProductService instances will be called in a round-robin (due to ribbon) fashion. Due to the fact that one of the ProductService instance always delivers exceptions, after doing multiple successive calls on the frontend, the ProductService circuit will be open (even though one of the instances of the ProductService can handle successfully the requests).

How can it be removed from eureka only the ProductService instance that has problems, and keep the ones functioning correctly, in order to avoid hystrix circuit breaking for ProductService?
I suppose that the functionality of the health indicator resource "/health" for ProductService needs to be changed to perform extra checks for system dependency failures.

I've stumbled on the use of [spring-boot-starter-actuator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready) where custom health checks can be performed, but this doesn't seem to help to take out the service instance from eureka.

Comment: Interesting.  Ribbon can take up to 30 seconds to update its list of servers.  If you wait a bit, does the circuit close again?

Comment: I've tried another time to use an own HealthIndicator  in order to simulate that the server is down. The server is shown in Eureka with status UP, but it is not called anymore by the ribbon clients. Shouldn't acutally the the service instance be marked as DOWN into Eureka?

Comment: I don't think eureka uses the `HealthIndicator` to determine if a service is down or not.